# Application is active in server but page is not loading, shows err - Access denied

Tags: deployment, weblogic12c

I was preparing production environment to deploy my ADF web application developed in jdeveloper 12.2.1. Installed and configured weblogic 12.2.1.1.0(latest version) and  database( Oracle DB 11g) in different servers. I tired to deploy a simple demo application which worked smoothly. But when i tired to deploy my application with MDS enabled which also having login credentials it's not get loading. Application and servers(3 managed servers added in a cluster) are active and its health is fine.
While I checked the log i can found the error message as below:

```
weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <OracleSystemUser> <BEA1-00A6CDC0DF4E2399D225> <c21c09b7-a391-47ae-b2eb-0d8dc5bec343-00000d61> <1477317511991> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-010227> <EJB exception occurred during invocation from home or business: oracle.wsm.policymanager.bean.ejb.impl.UsageTracker_oi3aq7_Intf generated exception
: java.lang.SecurityException: WSM-02084 : Access denied. Permission "oracle.wsm.security.PolicyManagerPermission" is required to access the wsm policy manager "UsageTracker" method "recordUsage".>
```

I am stuck with this issues. Tried by starting and stopping servers and deploy and undeploy application many times.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the suggestions on "SOA Suite 12.2.1 - OWSM WSM-02084 issue" from Michel Schildmeijer.

He suggests editing the `policy.Accessor` and adding `oracle.wsm.security.PolicyManagerPermission` for resource `UsageTracker#recordUsage` to the `wsm-pm` Application Stripe via "Fusion Middleware Control" under WebLogic Domain > Security > Application Policies.

https://community.oracle.com/blogs/mnemonic/2016/10/16/soa-suite-1221-owsm-wsm-02084-issue